# how to use certbot certificate on a django app via gunicorn an nginx?

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, certbot

i have a django app running on NGINX and created an ssl certificate successfully, when i run the web, it just time out and i have port 443 enabled.

```
server {
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    access_log off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
server {
     if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

     if ($host = example.com) {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot


server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

}

this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite shown above and running sudo ufw status outputs

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Apache Full                ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8000                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     DENY        Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80 on eth0                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8000 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                DENY        Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6) on eth0            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

why is my website not showing with https? where did i configure it wrong?

Comment: Which Linux distro are you using? Make sure the OS firewall is not blocking connections to the port 443.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Did you run ```sudo ufw allow 'Nginx Full'```?

Comment: yes, I did, and it's working. I think the problem is with the VM's Firewall as you suggested... let me fix that

Comment: Did you restart Nginx after creating SSL files .pem ?

Comment: yeah, i will delete the whole VM and start again